# WebStorm doesn't find ES6 named TypeScript import

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, webstorm

Getting a "Cannot resolve symbol" error when trying to use the named import syntax.

[image: resolve error]

The weird thing is that it works just fine with the `import * as ...` syntax.

[image: import star syntax]

I've set ES6 target in `tsconfig.json` and installed Lodash typings using `tsd`.

Comment: it works fine in VSCode and Atom, it just seems to be a Webstorm bug. Also lodash.d.ts declares _ as a global variable, so you don't need any imports, you can just use _. anywhere.

Comment: It does work using `_`, though I prefer to import the specific helpers.

Comment: then I would suggest you either make a bug for webstorm or use a better editor. :)

Comment: works fine for WS12 EAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @anstarovoyt mentioned, it works fine in WS 12 EAP due to the improved Typescript support. Oh, well.

Comment: Import React from 'react-native' works but destructuring doesn't.  Import { Text, View } from 'react-native' doesn't work.